# Initialization outside of main Java

Tags: java

My question is how initialize an 2-D array outside of the main, lets say I want to print number[0][0]
How would I go about accessing that specific variable from the main

```
public class Example{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Example myexample = new Example();
        myexample.definenumbers();
    }

    public void definenumbers()
    {
        int [][] number = 
        {
        {2,0},{3,1}
        };
    }
```

Comment: You can define `number` as a class level variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do,

```
public void definenumbers() {
    int [][] number = 
    {
    {2,0},{3,1}
    };
}
```

You have defined a method local variable named `number`. It is eligible for garbage collection when the method ends (since it is no longer reachable). You could return a reference to it,

```
public int[][] definenumbers() {
    int [][] number = 
    {
    {2,0},{3,1}
    };
    return number;
}
```

and then in in `main()` -

```
Example myexample = new Example();
int[][] number = myexample.definenumbers();
```

Alternatively, you could make it a field -

```
private int[][] number;
public int[][] getNumbers() {
    return number;
}
public void definenumbers() {
    number = 
    {
    {2,0},{3,1}
    };
}
```

Then in `main()`,

```
Example myexample = new Example();
myexample.definenumbers();
int[][] number =  myexample.getNumbers();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You made it easy to understand. Quick question, is fields a better approach for good programming habits?

Comment: @barapapupi It depends on what you're trying to do. `fields` are more reusable in the sense that you might preserve the value for multiple callers. On the other hand, it's a good practice to limit the scope to the minimum necessary for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public class Example{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Example myexample = new Example();
    int[][] number=myexample.definenumbers();
    System.out.println(number[0][0]);
}

public int[][] definenumbers()
{
    int [][] number = 
    {
    {2,0},{3,1}
    };
    return number;
}
}
```

or you can also define it as a class variable and access it anywhere in the class as said above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read about Classes,Objects, Scope of variables.
Start thinking in terms of object.

To provide a hint:

Design a class to have 2d array as your member.

Have a method to initialize that array.

Have getter methods or utility functions or member functions so as get data.

Start thinking and you would get the nack of things.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a class level variable.

```
 public class Example{
 Public int [][] number;
 //constructor
Example (){
int [][] arrayname={
        {2,0},{3,1}
        };
Number=arrayname;
}

    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Example myexample = new Example();
       System.out.println (myexample.number[0][0]);
    }
```